# Topic based authorization in RabbitMQ

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I am using RabbitMQ using C# client. I want to expose a web api using which external clients can publish in my RabbitMQ. Here I want to setup Topic based authorization like this:

If I have three topics configured on my RabbitMQ say Notification, SMS and Mail

- Client A : SMS, Mail rights
- Client B : Notification
- client C : Notification, SMS and Mail rights

So my questions is whether RabbitMQ provides any such authentication scheme for User authorization on Topics or I should implement my own mechanism for it?

I have found some discussion here:
[Topics based authentication in RabbitMQ](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/issues/505)
but no code piece or any confirmed information is available.

Comment: you go a short explication as you expect with any example :(. http://www.rabbitmq.com/authentication.html and short example here https://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v2.8.6/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-2.8.6-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.html i 'm no c# dev so gl i did it in java and php too and here http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/docs/enterprise/servers/oneviewhelp/oneviewRESTAPI/content/s_SCMB-dotNET-fusion.html

Comment: @headmax, I guess you did not understand the question properly. I know how to authenticate a user on RabbitMQ using C# client. My question is regarding the authorization based on Topics. The answer could be in terms of a policy or a C# code to do the same. so your comment is not an answer. If you have done it in Java, let me know. I am well aware with java also.

Comment: I guess :), i'am no a fluent english, so i did it a long time ago at work, I just remember the git using https://github.com/AzendInc/amqp_advanced_router it was useful for us but may be out of date and isn't what you are looking for... gl